# clang 14.00 : _GLIBCXX11_DEPRECATED_SUGGEST("std::bind");

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, guix

Installed clang 14.0 using GNU/Guix's clang-toolchain package.
I am getting depreciated feature usage error when
trying to compile a simple code:

```cpp
//build with: clang++ main.cpp
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  std::cout << "hello world!" << std::endl;
}
```

The error message is:

```
[Guix profile dir]/include/c++/backward/binders.h:130:6: error: expected ';' after class
    } _GLIBCXX11_DEPRECATED_SUGGEST("std::bind");
```

The error happens regardless of which STL header
the code includes. For example, it fails when `<string>`
is included with the same error message.

Any idea how to resolve the error?

**Update 1:**
This seems to be a configuration error. It goes away if the compilation is done inside a Guix container environment:

```sh
guix environment --container clang-toolchain -- clang++ main.cpp -o main
```

**Update 2:**

**[This turned out to be WRONG. It is related to lack of multilib support in gcc-toolchain]**

The error still persists when running the same code in a Guix  environment with the `--pure` option. This means the
error isn't due to environment setting.

There is also an older bug report addressing the same issue: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1896076. The
error message in the bug can be reproduced when running
the test code using emscripten:

```sh
emcc -o main.html main.cpp
```

The problem is the bug was already addressed in Fedora 33?
I am currently on: **Linux/fedora 5.17.4-200.fc35.x86_64** with
a Guix environment: `guix describe --format=channels`:

```lisp
(list (channel
        (name 'guix)
        (url "https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/guix.git")
        (branch "master")
        (commit
          "59b91fdbcd7e1a88d1d54d392ce5d5fddd9d96d1")
        (introduction
          (make-channel-introduction
            "9edb3f66fd807b096b48283debdcddccfea34bad"
            (openpgp-fingerprint
              "BBB0 2DDF 2CEA F6A8 0D1D  E643 A2A0 6DF2 A33A 54FA"))))
      (channel
        (name 'flat)
        (url "https://github.com/flatwhatson/guix-channel.git")
        (branch "master")
        (commit
          "f43c67e47f1ca83d045f35c31772c5e4eb64b2a2")
        (introduction
          (make-channel-introduction
            "33f86a4b48205c0dc19d7c036c85393f0766f806"
            (openpgp-fingerprint
              "736A C00E 1254 378B A982  7AF6 9DBE 8265 81B6 4490")))))
```

**Update 3:** It seems the latest *clang-toolchain@14.0.0* breaks when installed alongside *gcc-toolchain@11.2.0*. That is, in the same Guix profile. Downgrading *gcc-toolchain* to version *10.3.0* resolved the error.

The issue can be reproduced with:

```sh
guix shell clang-toolchain@14.0.0 gcc-toolchain@11.2.0 --container -- clang++ main.cpp
```

Output:

```sh
In file included from main.cpp:1:
In file included from /gnu/store/../profile/include/c++/iostream:39:
In file included from /gnu/store/../profile/include/c++/ostream:38:
In file included from /gnu/store/../profile/include/c++/ios:42:
In file included from /gnu/store/../profile/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41:
In file included from /gnu/store/../profile/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40:
In file included from /gnu/store/../profile/include/c++/string:48:
In file included from /gnu/store/../profile/include/c++/bits/stl_function.h:1407:
/gnu/store/../profile/include/c++/backward/binders.h:130:6: error: expected ';' after class
    } _GLIBCXX11_DEPRECATED_SUGGEST("std::bind");
     ^
/gnu/store/../profile/include/c++/backward/binders.h:130:7: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
    } _GLIBCXX11_DEPRECATED_SUGGEST("std::bind");
      ^
/gnu/store/../profile/include/c++/backward/binders.h:165:6: error: expected ';' after class
    } _GLIBCXX11_DEPRECATED_SUGGEST("std::bind");
     ^
/gnu/store/../profile/include/c++/backward/binders.h:165:7: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
    } _GLIBCXX11_DEPRECATED_SUGGEST("std::bind");
```

Downgrading gcc to *gcc-toolchain@10.3*:

```sh
guix shell clang-toolchain@14.0.0 gcc-toolchain@10.3.0 --container -- clang++ main.cpp
```

Output:
Expected file(a.out) is produced

Comment: Your error is a syntax error, missing `;`, not a deprecation error. I would check your installed library headers. Probably wrong.

Comment: The message doesn't really make sense, since the `;` is there in the code line shown in the message. The only explanation I have is that the macro expanded to something that clang doesn't understand, but I don't know why that should happen. How exactly did you install the toolchain and run the compiler? Since you are using guix, you should probably be able to provide a reproducible setup.

Comment: @user17732522 I installed the toolchain using a regular Guix command: `guix package install clang-toolchain`

Comment: I only have limited experience with guix, but what does e.g. `guix describe --format=channels` say about your environment? If you are simply running a default guix installation, I think you will be more successful reporting it as a bug to guix or asking their mailing list for help. If you modified something from a default installation, you should probably mention that. `guix package --export-manifest` might also help for reproducibility.

Comment: @user17732522 I did run both commands you suggested. The first command only shows the channels current in use. I use ```flatwhatson``` for Emacs, but that's about it. ```guix package --export-manifest``` returns empty output.

Comment: @aarongile `guix describe --format=channels` contains the commit hash of guix and additional channels which you are using. Knowing it would help others exactly reproducing your situation. I don't really see the linked bug report being the same problem. It fails there at a different point in the standard library headers. Anyway, I won't have time to try to reproduce it on my system. Maybe someone else does.